# I am creating an currency exchange command line application

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am creating an currency exchange command line application and i created an interface so that i can define structure of object array that will store the keys and values of currency name and its current value in international market and these i will get by using axios.

```js
type keye = string;
type value = number| string;

interface apidata{
    keye : value ,
}

let arr :  Array<apidata>;

const apiRequest = "https://api.exchangerate-api.com/v4/latest/USD";


let data = async () => {
    try{
        let response = await axios(apiRequest)
        let data : string = response.data.rates;
        return data;
    }catch(error){
        log(error);
    }
}
let x = await data();
```

I am writing code that can store the data in data variable which is object like this

```json
{
  USD: 1,   
  AED: 3.67,
  AFN: 87.04,
  ALL: 107.72,
  AMD: 394.86,
  ANG: 1.79,
  AOA: 510.25,
  ARS: 172.12,
  AUD: 1.49,
  AWG: 1.79,
  AZN: 1.7,
  BAM: 1.84,
  BBD: 2,
  BDT: 103.82,
  BGN: 1.84,
  BHD: 0.376,
  BIF: 2060.91,
  BMD: 1,
  BND: 1.36,
  BOB: 6.93,
so on
}
```

arr which is array stores object at 0 index which only one property as 'USD:1' and next object at index 1 with AED:3.67  data
so

I tried doing many things like store response data in json file

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: If you need just a refactor, and consulting, post it here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should update the question title to actually specify your question - not just state your task. That is not helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're doing, but this might be what you want:

If you need data like (This is in line with the type of arr you are declaring):

```js
[
  { USD: 1 },
  { AED: 3.67 },
  ...
]
```

use code:

```
arr = Object.entries(x).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }))
```

> I understand what you're trying to declare arr, but you did it the wrong way. Maybe you want it to be like this:

```
type keye = string;
type value = number| string;

interface apidata {
    [key: keye]: value ,
}
```

---

if you need data like:

```js
[
  ["USD", 1],
  ["AED", 3.67],
  ...
]
```

use code:

```
arr = Object.entries(x)
```